# Wordpress: Show posts based on custom field

Tags: wordpress

I have a slider script for my homepage (wp nivo slider), but only want to show slides (posts) if todays date is before post_end_date (custom field). This is so that I do not have to manually remove posts that are no longer relevant.

This is the code that loads the posts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Custom post field: **post_end_date**

```
<?php
    $category = get_option('wpns_category');
    $n_slices = get_option('wpns_slices');
?>
<?php query_posts( 'cat='.$category.'&posts_per_page=$n_slices' ); if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endwhile; endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

in this function  $postid is that  id of wich is coming in loop and key is that name of custom field  last in $single you can write  true of false
get the custom fild by this function after that  try the if condition for you custom postfeild  values

hope this will help you